# Spring REST Integration tests, entity is not deleted

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, spring-data-jpa

I have a UserControllerTest which is testing my UserConstroller. There is a test:

```
@Test
public void shouldRemoveUser() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(put("/user/register?email=test5@gmail.com&password=aaa"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

    mockMvc.perform(get("/user?email=test5@gmail.com"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

    mockMvc.perform(delete("/user?email=test5@gmail.com"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

    mockMvc.perform(get("/user?email=test5@gmail.com"))
            .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
}
```

And the implementation which I want to test:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "register")
public ResponseEntity<?> createUser(
        @RequestParam(value = "email") String email,
        @RequestParam(value = "password", defaultValue = "") String password) {


    MyUser myUser = new [...]
    userRepository.save(myUser );
    return ResponseEntity.ok(myUser);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@RequestParam(value = "email") String email) {
    MyUser userByEmail = userRepository.findMyUserByEmail(email);
    if (userByEmail == null) {
        LOG.debug("Cannot delete user with id: {}", email);
        throw new UserNotFoundException("Cannot find user with email: " + email);
    }
    userRepository.delete(userByEmail);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

Turns out that the method `delete` works perfectly fine when fired via Postman or any other Rest Client. However, in tests the result is as follows:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :404
Actual   :200
```

It seams like the user is somehow not deleted when the code runs in tests.

In test I used H2, but when I tried to test it manually via Postman I used PostgreSQL.

Comment: Maybe because your mock is expecting the status as `OK` in the case of `delete` in `mockMvc.perform(delete("/user?email=test5@gmail.com")).andExpect(status().isOk());`

Comment: The problem is that the `userRepository` finds the user with email `test5@gmail.com` (which was removed the moment before). There should be thrown exception `UserNotFoundException` which is handled as a `404`

Comment: You are saying that next call to `get()` finds the User which should have been removed by the `delete()` in the earlier step? Can you try performing another `delete()` operation in your test immediately after the first delete and see the behaviour?

Comment: Your comment gave me a suggestion which solved the problem. I had two methods mappings ( `user?email=blahblahblah`   which returns a details of the user with the specified email, and method `user` which returns all the users). As you probably know the calls in tests hits the second method which always return `200`, but the array of users was simply empty. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I'm glad that it solved your problem. Have a great day ahead! :)

Comment: Btw, after more than 6 years of using StackOverflow I finally can upvote... Thanks!

Comment: Hahaha. Cheers! :)